# use .split() for files. java

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have a file and want to split the file line by line. But I do not want to create a new file each time. just store every line in an Array.
the .split() method is exactly what I want but it can't be used for files.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class Read{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
            File datei = new File("file.txt");
            String[] splitDatei = datei.split(System.lineSeparator());


            myReader.close();


        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe `BufferedReader.lines()` followed by `Stream.toArray()` - or `Files.readAllLines()` with `List.toArray()` (if an array is really required)

Comment: *`"want to create a new file each time"`* - but you're only reading a file in your code, and **not** creating a new file or writing anything. You need to describe your intention at least in pseudocode. Do you want to split each line of your file into multiple lines, and then write this data into a newly created file?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko maybe what I wrote was misleading. I said that I DO NOT want to create a new file each time. just split the file line by line and store each line in a new array entry.

Comment: @user16320675 It doesn't HAVE to be an array. Although I thought that that'd be the best way to store such data, wouldn't it?  Because storing each line in a new String variable wouldn't be very smart since it would create many many variables if there are many many entries in the file. what would be an alternative to arrays?

Comment: *"split the file line by line and store each line in a new array entry"* - what do you mean by that? *"array entry"* means an array element? So each array element should contain a **line of text**? And result should of type `String[]`?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko yes exactly. the line of text wont be long and without spaces . And I do think that String[ ] is the best way to store such data, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

There is `java.nio.file.Files#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)` method:

```
List<String> stringList = Files.readAllLines(Path.of("file.txt"));
```

or `java.nio.file.Files#lines(java.nio.file.Path)` (you can can get a stream and then convert it to an array):

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Path.of("file.txt"))) {
    String[] strings = stream.toArray(String[]::new);
} catch (IOException e) {
    //
}
```

Docs:

[Files#readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-)

[Files#lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)

Comment: I can't test that right now. But thank you very much for your proposal. Does this Split the file on every line and store each line in the array?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't even appear that you are making use of your scanner in the code that you linked.

If you need to use the Scanner to do it, then you can use a variation of the following code. Though I recommend using star67's solution followed by a .toArray(new String[0]); call.

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
File datei = new File("file.txt");
Scanner myReader = new Scanner(datei);
while(myReader.hasNextLine())
{
    lines.add(myReader.nextLine());
}
myReader.close();
final String[] linesArray = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: If you do it like this, I would suggest the `Path`-constructor for the `Scanner`, and create it in a try-with-resources block, ie `try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(Paths.of("file.txt")) { ... } `

Comment: I believe the #of method is only available in the "Path" class as opposed to "Paths" and was introduced in Java 11. Paths has a very similar method called #get that can be used since Java 7.

Comment: You're right, I meant `Paths.get()`. My suggestion stands.